# How do I resolve code relating to "instantiate"?

Tags: java

So, I am writing a code in which I imported a class with class name "Workbook" and function "createWorkBook". I asked the same question earlier but I wanted to add changes so I removed that before anyone could reply.

Anyways, 
I am new to Java , interfaces and importing class.
I imported a package named "jxl" and I am using it. Here is my FULL code so far.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.*;
import jxl.write.*;
import jxl.write.Number;

public class WriteExcel {
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException , WriteException
{
    try{
        Workbook wb = new Workbook();
        }
    catch(WriteException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, failed! Keep on trying harder! :)");
    }
    }
}
```

ALL I am trying for past half an hour is trying to make an object "wb" in class "workbook" .
I followed bit of instructions from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9866lBdmKo (importing of class).

I am getting an error for the link Workbook wb= new Workbook();
Cannot instantiate the Workbook type. I did some research turns out it is relating to some "interface". But the video didn't even talk about interface. I am new and would like some guidance. I just want to create one object.

So I got the file, thanks for ANY sort of input!

Comment: Don't follow videos. Read the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: If you want to change a question, you don't have to remove it and repost it, you can just edit it..

Comment: Oh, but we all love it when we start answering a question, then it gets removed just before we can click "Post your answer".  And we especially love it when the same question appears a little while later.  Having to type everything all over again really motivates us to make double the effort to produce a good answer.

Comment: Is Workbook an interface?

Comment: Sorry. Well, I it says Workbook.class on the imported files. I think it is a class but then why is it giving that error ?

Comment: Thank you to whoever replied! :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Workbook is an Anonymous Inner Type java class, whenever you want to instantiate that class, we'll need to override several methods. You will have to implement those methods. You can find more about Anonymous Inner Type java class here 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at the [javadoc](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html), it seems that `Workbook` is an `abstract class`, so you can't instanciate it, but it seems that it provides some `static`methods called `createWorkbook()` that you can use, like that :

```
Workbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("/path/to/the/workbook/file"));
```

Comment: I understood what you said but now I am getting error related to "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"  Do you understand what it means?

Comment: @ToxicGlow Go ahead and put that error message into the search engine of your choice; there should plenty out there that already explains it.

Answer (score 0):

As workbook is an abstract class. The only way to create a workbook object is

String fileName = "file.xls";

WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(fileName));

Creates a writable workbook with the given file name.

Also please refer to the below link that represent the workbook class and its methods

http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html

Comment: Why is it "WriteableWork" and not simply "Workbook"?